# Change log4j settings in Camel TestSupport

Tags: java, junit, log4j, apache-camel

I am debugging some jUnit tests that use the Camel TestSupport interface. This gives me access to a log4j log but I can't seem to figure out how to get a reconfigured version of that. I want to be able to change the log level since a lot of my logs are written in a trace level instead of just info or debug.

What is the best way to reconfigure this log's console output?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a log4j.xml or log4j.properties on your classpath that you're using the test.

If you're using maven, this is easy, just put it in `src/test/resources`.